# external .env for bundled vue-cli SPA

Tags: vue.js, webpack, single-page-application

I tried to use dotenv-webpack, but the .env also included in the bundle.
What I wanted to do is to make the .env readable after the build.

```
static/ 
index.html
.env
```

is this possible on spa's?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with the standard Vue-CLI/Webpack unless you search inside the bundled gibberish of your code.

If your intention is to do something with the bundled data like changing values inside your .env then there is a way to hook your app with a `env.js` file, but this should not contain sensitive data.

#### Explanation of post- "env.js" hook:

you have to check for a global variable somewhere in you code.
i make a example of changing the axios baseURL after bundling the project.

place a js file like "env.js" in the first place of initialization in your web server.

```js
// env.js
document.env = 'https://www.use-other-api.com'
```

so "document.env" is now declared before your app runs

then you have a hook in your project which is prepared for this "after bundled env changes"
like:

```js
if (document.env === 'https://www.use-other-api.com') {
   // change axios baseURL to "document.env"
} else {
   // stay default baseURl
}
```

and that's it.
just be aware of not using any sensitive data in this scope because it is accessible anywhere in your app.
like i would not recommend you to put in some secrets depending in your backend stuff.

Comment: please put example for the last point

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI added example and explanation

Answer (score 0):

No, the `.env` file should be loaded on the server that runs your app. That's what it's name stands for. It consists of enviromental variables that you can use globally.

You can find more...
https://codeburst.io/process-env-what-it-is-and-why-when-how-to-use-it-effectively-505d0b2831e7

Comment: I think the author is junior and doesn't understand how enviromental variables work. He just want to build a static site, that makes requests to an external api, and host it.
Sorry if i got that wrong.